Optimizing the Calculation of the Dot Product of int16 Vectors in Java using Vector API
TL;DR: Optimizing 16 bit integer array multiplications without overflowing using Java's Vector API.
I am trying to optimize a performance-critical loop that applies an activation function and calculates the dot product of two int16 arrays using Java's (incubating) Vector API. Here's my current scalar implementation:
for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++)
{
    result += screlu(us.values[i]) * network.L1Weights[i]
        + screlu(them.values[i]) * network.L1Weights[i + HIDDEN_SIZE];
}

where
private static int screlu(short i)
{
    int v = Math.max(0, Math.min(i, QA));
    return v * v;
}

I tried to vectorize this like so:
int[] usValues = new int[HIDDEN_SIZE];
int[] themValues = new int[HIDDEN_SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_SIZE; i++)
{
    usValues[i] = (int) us.values[i];
    themValues[i] = (int) them.values[i];
}

IntVector sum = IntVector.zero(INT_SPECIES);

for (; i < upperBound; i += INT_SPECIES.length())
{
    IntVector va = IntVector.fromArray(INT_SPECIES, usValues, i);
    IntVector vb = IntVector.fromArray(INT_SPECIES, themValues, i);
    IntVector vc = IntVector.fromArray(INT_SPECIES, network.L1Weights, i);
    IntVector vd = IntVector.fromArray(INT_SPECIES, network.L1Weights, i + HIDDEN_SIZE);

    va = va.max(0).min(QA);
    va = va.mul(va).mul(vc);

    vb = vb.max(0).min(QA);
    vb = vb.mul(vb).mul(vd);

    sum = sum.add(va).add(vb);
}

int result = sum.reduceLanes(VectorOperators.ADD);

Due to overflow, I had to resort to using 32-bit wide lanes, halving the throughput. As a result, performance is only slightly better. After some research, I found that intrinsic such as _mm256_madd_epi16 solves exactly my problem, but I could not find any information on it in the documentation. Do any equivalent operation exist within the Vector API, and if not, are there any other solutions to this problem?

It doesn't look like there's an equivalent operation, no.

You're correct that the x86 instruction vpmaddwd is perfect for this, accumulating horizontal pairs into 32-bit sums.  I have no idea if Java's SIMD API exposes anything that could hopefully compile to that, though.  AArch64 ASIMD has a somewhat different insn that also works for dot products, smlal (and smlal2 for the high half).  https://godbolt.org/z/Gf6qfq9nc shows clang auto-vectorizing with it.  Two vectors of data from each array feed two pairs of smlal / smlal2 instructions which multiply 16-bit sources and accumulate into 32-bit elements of the destination.

So it's different functionality, not horizontally adding pairs.  IDK if AArch64 has that as a single instruction, maybe only x86-64, so a "portable" SIMD API like Java's might not provide either.  :/  Both are fully usable for dot products, but that's a higher-level operation.

With some help I eventually figured out an implementation using the S2I operator, which is faster than the scalar implementation but probably slower than what could've been done had vpmaddwd been available.
import static jdk.incubator.vector.VectorOperators.S2I;

for (int i = 0; i < UPPERBOUND; i += SHORT_SPECIES.length())
{
    ShortVector usInputs = ShortVector.fromArray(SHORT_SPECIES, us.values, i);
    ShortVector themInputs = ShortVector.fromArray(SHORT_SPECIES, them.values, i);
    ShortVector usWeights = ShortVector.fromArray(SHORT_SPECIES, network.L2Weights[chosenBucket], i);
    ShortVector themWeights = ShortVector.fromArray(SHORT_SPECIES, network.L2Weights[chosenBucket],
            i + HIDDEN_SIZE);

    usInputs = usInputs.max(ShortVector.zero(SHORT_SPECIES)).min(ShortVector.broadcast(SHORT_SPECIES, QA));
    themInputs = themInputs.max(ShortVector.zero(SHORT_SPECIES)).min(ShortVector.broadcast(SHORT_SPECIES, QA));

    ShortVector usWeightedTerms = usInputs.mul(usWeights);
    ShortVector themWeightedTerms = themInputs.mul(themWeights);

    Vector<Integer> usInputsLo = usInputs.convert(S2I, 0);
    Vector<Integer> usInputsHi = usInputs.convert(S2I, 1);
    Vector<Integer> themInputsLo = themInputs.convert(S2I, 0);
    Vector<Integer> themInputsHi = themInputs.convert(S2I, 1);

    Vector<Integer> usWeightedTermsLo = usWeightedTerms.convert(S2I, 0);
    Vector<Integer> usWeightedTermsHi = usWeightedTerms.convert(S2I, 1);
    Vector<Integer> themWeightedTermsLo = themWeightedTerms.convert(S2I, 0);
    Vector<Integer> themWeightedTermsHi = themWeightedTerms.convert(S2I, 1);

    sum = sum.add(usInputsLo.mul(usWeightedTermsLo)).add(usInputsHi.mul(usWeightedTermsHi))
    .add(themInputsLo.mul(themWeightedTermsLo)).add(themInputsHi.mul(themWeightedTermsHi));
}

int result = sum.reduceLanes(VectorOperators.ADD);


Yeah, if that compiles / JITs as written, it's probably terrible on x86, like vpmovsxwd widening the inputs for slow vpmulld 32x32 -> 32-bit multiplies (2 uops per instruction on Intel, and doing half as many products, and requiring more add instructions).  A clever-enough JIT could I think optimize to vpmaddwd, but only if it realizes the whole thing is a reduction of sums of products, since the temporaries are different.  I guess faster than scalar is better than nothing, and you're getting the SIMD min/max clamping operation vectorized efficiently.
